# Right way to transfer millions of rows from source database table to destination database table

Tags: sql-server, pentaho, etl, kettle

I have been running into the same problem and don't have a good general solution -

The scenario is:

- I have a source table in a database (like MS SQL Server) that has a
  few million rows.  With a couple Gb of table data overall.
- I want to
  insert those rows into a destination table in another system.  This
  part I feel comfortable and seems to work well.

The issue is that running a single thread to read all X million rows in a single select/connection always runs into problems.  So I would like Pentaho to enable me to say make multiple selects and process 100K or 500K rows per "batch" and keep processing until there are no more rows.

I can hard-code a simple script to run pan.sh with a named parameters for a start row and batch size - that works great but I have to pre-calculate the script steps and actual starting row numbers.

Ideally I wish Pentaho could set a "Number of Copies" and a batch size on the Table Input step so it would be automagic!

Does someone have sample job definition that gets a row count for a table - then "loops" a call to the transformation until all rows are processed?  Maybe some chunk of the batches could run in parallel for extra credit.

Comment: Well it's not exactly automagic, but PDI can do [partitioning](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Partitioning+data+with+PDI). This article is focused on partitioning after you read the data though. If you right click on a `Table Input` step, the partitioning selection is available, but I don't know if this will work on a table input step.

Comment: This is intriguing - but it deals with data after it has been turned into rows -- as you say ideally I want a way to split up the table input step to pull partitions of the source table.

Comment: Let's hope @codek sees this post.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, you called?

Yes; the way to do that is indeed to use multiple copies and then to use the "number" of the step and the mod function.

So; if you have 2 copies of the step, if you say:

```
where rownum % 2 = 0
```

in the query then you'll pull out every second row.

rownum could be an ID or some other numeric column - needs to be an evenly spread ID of course. Also helps if its indexed - and especially good if it is part of the underlying database partition.

This approach works really well for slow network connections too - lets you load up multiple connections to the database.

Doco on the variables to use in this jira:

http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-3253

Its then your choice if you wish to keep the "partition" flowing downstream.

Comment: I can see using this approach to be able to multi-thread the Table Input step.

Comment: My original question was trying to address a problem we have seen (especially with MS SQL Server) where we felt like the input needed to be batched in specific-sized chunks - so that the connection would be closed, then re-opened for the next batch to process.  The problem was - how to make a PDI job do something like a for/loop with a step increment to loop through batches until count(*) records are processed.

Comment: In that case, use the "execute for every row" option, and pass in a data set that defines the min/max values for each trunk - and use those values for the where clause.